# C# EF Core - conflito de simultaneidade com trigger mariadb

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core, mariadb

Estou utilizando **EF Core** com **mariadb**, no banco tenho campos com valores padrões definidos e uma `trigger` "`before insert`".

No mapeamento fluente, informo os valores padrões ao campo normalmente.
Porém se tento fazer o insert nessa tabela ocorre erro de simultaneidade, e não consigo encontrar uma solução nativa para isso.

Para teste, removi os valores padrões definidos aos campos e removi também do mapeamento, dessa forma funciona. Porém preciso desses valores padrões definidos.

O erro que está ocorrendo é este:

> "Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected
>   0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were
>   loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for
>   information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency
>   exceptions."

Mapeamento fluente:

```
public class ProdutoConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Produto>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Produto> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(p => new { p.Filial, p.ProdutoId });

        builder.Property(p => p.ProdutoId).HasColumnName("ProdutoId");
        builder.Property(p => p.Descricao).HasColumnName("Descricao");
        builder.Property(p => p.Valor).HasColumnName("Valor");
        builder.Property(p => p.Tipo).HasColumnName("Tipo").HasDefaultValue("F");
        builder.Property(p => p.Filial).HasColumnName("Filial");
    }
}
```

Trigger:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `tg_produto_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `produto` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE idGerado INT;

    IF(NEW.ProdutoId IS NULL OR NEW.ProdutoId = 0) THEN

        SET idGerado = (SELECT COALESCE((SELECT UltimoGerado + 1 FROM Sequenciador WHERE Tabela = 'produto' AND Filial = NEW.Filial), 0));

        IF(idGerado = 0) THEN
            INSERT INTO Sequenciador (Filial, Tabela, UltimoGerado) VALUES (NEW.Filial, 'produto', 1);
            SET idGerado = 1;
        ELSE
            UPDATE Sequenciador SET UltimoGerado = idGerado WHERE Tabela = 'produto' AND Filial = NEW.Filial;
        END IF;

        SET NEW.ProdutoId = idGerado;

    ELSEIF(NEW.ProdutoId < 0) THEN
        SET NEW.ProdutoId = 
            (SELECT CASE WHEN COALESCE(ProdutoId, -1) > -1 THEN -1 ELSE (ProdutoId -1) END ProdutoId FROM Produto ORDER BY ProdutoId ASC LIMIT 1);
    END IF;
END
```

Comment: Disponibiliza o código do se mapeamento fluent. Creio que pode ser algo por ali.